# Ruby on Rails item creation URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've noticed a small issue that bugs me in a couple of my Rails applications, which I've also seen in the Railscasts episodes.

As a blog application example, if a user browses to "/posts", they're presented with a list of posts. When a user wants to add a post, they visit "/posts/new", which is fine.

My problem occurs when the user submits their form with validation errors, the "/posts/new" form is rendered, but with the "/posts" URL. As an example, in the validation section of Michael Hartl's [Rails Tutorial user signup section](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec%3asignup_failure) (Figure 8.7), you can see the URL is just "/users", not "/users/new" as the form that is being displayed would suggest.

Is there some kind of routing that I'm missing? I can't post code at the moment, as I'm away from my work computer (I'll post it if necessary later on), but as far as I can see/remember, I'm using the methods taught in [Michael Hartl's tutorial](http://railstutorial.org/book).

It's not a massive problem. It just irks me a little, and any help on why it does this would be greatly appreaciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a normal behavior.

When you submit a form with a new object, you make a POST request to `create` method, which url is "/posts" (see `rake routes`). If any errors exist this method renders a new action without any redirection to other methods/urls. It simply takes a template for `new` action and provides an object with errors.

Comment: That makes sense. I understand that it's to do with the RESTful approach, in that the HTTP header has a different affect on what URL it accesses. It's just I'm not 100% happy that the form is only "rendered" after the POST to the `new` action, not redirected. But you say this is just normal behaviour, not an issue I should be concerned with?

Comment: Yes, Rich, it's ok. Users won't notice it. I strained at the beginning too :).

Answer (score 0):

thats because by default rails adopt RESTful approach. REST (Representational State Transfer) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer)

in REST you have following http verbs

GET

POST

PUT

DELETE

So when you consider posts controller

**index** action is by default **GET**

Ex: `/ports/`

will return all the ports

**show** action is by default **GET**

```
/ports/1
```

will return post which id is 1

**new** action **GET**

```
/posts/new
```

will return a new post object

**edit** is **GET**

```
/posts/1/edit
```

will return the post object which id is 1, for editing

**create** is **POST**

when you say

/posts/ with http POST, rails will expect a post object (thats why you see only posts/) in the url (underline it goes as a POST request)

**update** is **PUT**

when you say

/posts/ with http PUT, rails will expect a post object to edit (thats why you see only posts/) in the url (underline it goes as a PUT request)

**destroy** is **DELETE**

destroy will work as http DELETE request

have a look at this example also

http://blogs.sitepoint.com/restful-rails-part-i/

HTH

sameera